# How to configure AWS API gateway to work with basic http authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-authentication, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to configure AWS API Gateway for a Lambda function which receive the event Webhook request from Sendgrid (https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html).

The requests will be sent from outside of my internal system so I want to have some kind of authentication for it. But according to Sendgrid'd documents, only basic http authentication is supported. The URL will look like : *http(s)://username:password@domain/foo.php*

I have no idea how to setting up API Gateway so it can at least pass the username and password to the Lambda function.